# Docker commit and get rid of old images

Tags: docker

I have to keep committing on running docker containers, with timestamp tags.
This creates new docker images.

Now, I want to get rid of old images from which the container was spawned in the beginning, cause it wont be used anymore.

I can write code to do this using a lot of logic and regex but,
Is there any other graceful way to do this?

How does the docker community do this?

Please let me know if the question does not belong here and belongs somewhere else before downvoting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean up unused Docker images at any time using this command:

```
docker image prune -a
```

This will remove all Docker images without at least one container associated to them. This [includes dangling images](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/):

> *-a* Remove all unused images, not just dangling ones

Comment: Don't forget it also removes dangling images (images without tag)

Comment: @herm The `-a` flag seems to include dangling images, see quote from docs in my edit.